# Matplotlib Plot function returns lines in a same plot,

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The current plot generates only one line but I want multiple lines in the same plot iterating through variables in data frame `df2`

Now I am stuck as the return of a function is data frame and how can I store it in `'plot3'`variable?

How can I plot `wp(i)`, `tempp(i)` {5 sets of date} and etcs in same plots.

Representative plot:

![][1]

```
import pandas as pd
import random
def function(ConstantA, ConstantB, tst, temp, dtube):
    # some function
    randomlist = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        n = random.randint(1, 30)
    wp= ConstantA * randomlist
    tempp=ConstantB * randomlist
    ycp = tst * randomlist
    yap = temp * randomlist
    pp = dtube * randomlist


    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ConstantA, ConstantB, tst, temp, dtube)),
                   columns=['ConstantA', 'ConstantB', 'tst', 'temp', 'dtube'])

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    plot3 = function(row['ConstantA'], row['ConstantB'], row['tst'], row['temp'], row['dtube'])

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig.suptitle('Cooled;Tst=523')
ax1.plot(wp, tempp)
ax1.set_ylabel('T(K)')
ax2.plot(wp, ycp)
ax2.set_ylabel('y(C%)')
ax3.plot(wp, yap)
ax3.set_ylabel('yA ()')
ax3.set_xlabel('w (1000 ka)')
ax4.plot(wp, pp)
ax4.set_ylabel('E (bar)')
ax4.set_xlabel('w (1000 kg)')

plt.tight_layout()  # Automatic adjustment of pyplot so ylabels dont overlap
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)  # Adjust plots to put space beween title and subplot
plt.show()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'wp' is not defined. There is also an indentation mistake when you `return` in your function. Please post something that we can reproduce.

Comment: @ Alessandro Peca is it okay now?

Comment: every `plot` should gives value `ax` (for axis) and you can use it in next plot to display in the same plot

Comment: if you run `for`-loop on list (or DataFrame) then you should keep results also in list. `plot3.apppend(...)` But I think you could do the same using `df2.apply(function, axis=1)` and `def function(row): ...` and then you don't need for-loop and you can assing directly to `plot3`

Comment: you forgot `randomlist.append( n )` and you always have empty list

Comment: but there is another problem - `randomlist` is normal list and you have to use `for`-loop to calculate `ConstantA * randomlist`, or you would have to convert `randomlist` to numpy array or DataFrame` to do it withou `for`-loop. OR you should calculate ti directly inside current `for`-loop and do `wp.append( ConstantA * n )`. But it will be simpler to use `numpy` like `randomlist = np.random.randint(1, 30, size=5)`

Comment: after washing your code I think you have wrong indentations. You should create `fig, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4` before `for`-loop and later plot inside `for`-loop.

Comment: Thank you! but "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apppend'" Whan I am trying to plot3.apppend

Comment: it has to bee `append` with 2 `p` but you have with 3 `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few problems.

You should create `fig, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4` before `for`-loop and later plot `plot3` inside `for`-loop. This way you will draw on the same plots.

You should use `numpy` to generate `randomlist` because you can't do `ConstantA * randomlist` when `randomlist` is normal list.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- functions ---

def function(row):
    randomlist = np.random.randint(1, 30, size=5)

    return pd.DataFrame({
                'wp':    randomlist * row['ConstantA'],
                'tempp': randomlist * row['ConstantB'],
                'ycp':   randomlist * row['tst'],
                'yap':   randomlist * row['temp'],
                'pp':    randomlist * row['dtube']
            })
    
# --- main ---

data = {
    'ConstantA': [0.01545, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6],
    'ConstantB': [0.6885e-6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'tst': [523, 529, 531, 527, 533],
    'temp': [523, 524, 524, 524, 524],
    'dtube': [0.041, 0.041, 0.041, 0.041, 0.041]
}    

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# before `for`-loop

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig.suptitle('Cooled;Tst=523')
ax1.set_ylabel('T(K)')
ax2.set_ylabel('y(C%)')
ax3.set_ylabel('yA ()')
ax3.set_xlabel('w (1000 ka)')
ax4.set_ylabel('E (bar)')
ax4.set_xlabel('w (1000 kg)')

# `for`-loop

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plot3 = function(row)
    
    ax1.plot(plot3['wp'], plot3['tempp'])
    ax2.plot(plot3['wp'], plot3['ycp'])
    ax3.plot(plot3['wp'], plot3['yap'])
    ax4.plot(plot3['wp'], plot3['pp'])

# after `for`-loop

plt.tight_layout()  # Automatic adjustment of pyplot so ylabels dont overlap
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)  # Adjust plots to put space beween title and subplot
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it says TypeError: plot() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'ConstantB', 'tst', 'temp', and 'dtube'    ## please see the full code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16nQrtNJNNRKElI7UoWsEoBfgCLCEX2pP?usp=sharing

Comment: in my version I use `def function(row)` and later I run `plot3 = function(row)` . BTW: code on Colab works correctly for me. It seems you used my code with your `def function(ConstantA, ConstantB, tst, temp, dtube):` - so you will have to use also `plot3 = function(row['ConstantA'], row['ConstantB'], row['tst'], row['temp'], row['dtube'])`. But I made changes in `function` because it didn't work and your original `function` will not work.